# Prev/Next Links Broken on Static Front Page Pagination

Tags: php, functions, pagination

I've taken the example straight from the codex on this one, and my pagination is broken.

Here's the codex page I copied/pasted the code from:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link

Everything is working. My posts are showing, and I get **only** the `next_posts_link`, however it only works until page `2`. The `previous_posts_link` never appears.

I can only paginate to page 2, and I cannot go back or further.

I'm using WordPress 3.5.2 and I have reset my permalinks after attempting this.

I put a little debug section below to find how many max pages there are, the `var_dump`  returns `float(87)`.

And here's my PHP code. Any thoughts?

```
function homepage_test() {
    // Set the limit of posts to show per page
    $limit = 5;
    // set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=' . $limit . '&paged=' . $paged . '&orderby=date&order=DESC' );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    // the loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

        the_title();
    endwhile;

    // usage with max_num_pages
    next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
    //Debug to show how many max pages.
    var_dump($the_query->max_num_pages);
    previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );

    // clean up after our query
    wp_reset_postdata();
    else: ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Comment: Adjusting pagination in template is extremely unreliable. You need to be doing this in `pre_get_posts` hook or in othe way before template is reached.

Comment: And trying to paginate secondary queries with the ordinary `*_posts_link` functions is difficult if not impossible. Please take a look at the numerous "pagination" questions on the right under "Related".

Comment: If it's difficult, why do they have it listed in the codex as an example (and even say, `"set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)"`)? Most of the related posts deal with `get_query_var( 'page' )`, which I'm not having a problem with.

Comment: @Rarst, I played with `pre_get_posts`, but it doesn't seem to be changing the outcome. Prev/Next links are still broken and/or only going to page 2. `function homepage_posts( $query ) { if ( is_front_page() ) { $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 ); return; } } add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'homepage_posts', 1 );`

Comment: Also, I installed wp_pagenavi, and that's also not working. I'm at a complete loss with the code above and getting a page navigation working for paginated static front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`previous_posts_link()` echos the result of `get_previous_posts_link()` which checks the `paged` query variable, not the `page` query variable used on static pages. You will have to write your own code to display the link on a static page.

I didn't test it, but you might try fooling WordPress:

```
function homepage_test() {
    global $paged;
```

Now your changes to the $paged variable in your code will be seen by `get_previous_posts_link()`. I don't know what else it might affect or if the link will be correct.

Comment: As it looks right now, this seems to work great! (Won't know more until I get further into it, but at least I'm not stuck). Thanks!!